# Trouble setting up ActiveRecord many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm having some difficulty in getting a many to many relationship working in my Rails app. I'm running Ruby 2.2.2p95 and Rails 4.2.0.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Topic id: 1>
seeds.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
```

My video model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :topic
end
```

The topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :video
end
```

The join table migration:

```
class TopicsVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :topics_videos, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :topic_id, index: true
      t.belongs_to :video_id, index: true
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :topics_videos
  end
end
```

The error is happening in the db seeder:

```
62 | @topicTest= Topic.create!(title: 'Test')
63 | Video.create!(title: 'Test', topic: @topicTest)
```

I'm still really new to Rails, coming from PHP, and this one is stumping me at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as for a php comer this will be useful read: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Thanks man, I'll definitely read through that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `has_and_belongs_to_many` association names should be plural.

Video model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end
```

Topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end
```

Then you can use `create` method added by `has_and_belongs_to_many`

```
@topicTest= Topic.create!(title: 'Test')
@topicTest.videos.create!(title: 'Test')
```

Or

```
@topicTest= Topic.create!(title: 'Test')
@topicNew= Topic.create!(title: 'New')

video = Video.create!(title: 'Test')
@topicTest.videos << video
@topicNew.videos << video
```

For more details, refer to [HABTM section in Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference)

Comment: If I were to create a video through a topic, how would I then associate it with other topics?

Comment: Updated the answer to answer your query.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about the bitwise operator. Thanks Nitish, that's perfect!

Comment: `<<` is a method, not bitwise operator.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just used to calling them bitwise operators, obviously I understand that it's not shifting anything, it's just assigning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pluralize the relationship model like so:

**The video model:**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end
```

**The topic model:**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end
```